# Do Hubbard parameters depend on the localisation of Wannier orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, bose-hubbard-model

Wannier orbitals are not unique and depend on a choice of phase of the Bloch wave functions. This typically leads to people attempting to define Wannier functions such that they are "maximally localised" (see, for example, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function)).

Based on Wannier orbitals, one often then defines the Hubbard Model parameters, i.e., the onsite interaction $U$ and the hopping $t$. For example, when calculating the on-site interaction for a Coulomb potential,
\begin{align*}
U = \int d^3x \, d^3x ' |w(\vec x)|^2 |w(\vec x')|^2 V_{\rm c} (|\vec x-\vec x'|),
\end{align*}
where $w(\vec x)$ is the Wannier orbital on a particular site and $V_{\rm c}(\vec x)$ is the bare Coulomb interaction.

**Questions:** If the Wannier orbitals are not unique, then are the Hubbard parameters also not unique? If so, does this mean a particular system could have multiple Hubbard Model representations, where some are more valid in ignoring, e.g., nearest neighbour interactions?

Comment: All of the Hubbard models are the *same* if you are including all of the *bands*. It's only when you restrict to keeping only the lowest band(s) that the models will yield different numerical results.  So, to the extent that you are keeping enough bands, the calculations will be the same. It's hard to say that one choice of Wannier functions "captures" the nearest-neighbor interactions better than the other.  I suppose you could do some sort of perturbation theory justification for ignoring bands or something...

Comment: That's a nice point that Hubbard models are all the same when you include all the bands. I also agree that the justification of ignoring nearest-neighbour interactions comes from perturbation theory - effectively zeroth order perturbation theory. However, doesn't this argument mean that the Hubbard model which has the smallest nearest-neighbour interaction is precisely the one that "captures" the nearest-neighbour interaction the best once we truncate the model and ignore these interactions?

Comment: I think that that's a really hard question to answer.  I could see a large-enough overlap between Wannier states between bands that the overlap of the interaction "beats" the energy offset between the bands, making the nearest-neighbor interactions relatively *strong*. Choosing highly localized Wannier states and then restricting to only the lowest bands might then *miss* this physics. I feel like you can really only answer this question by choosing a (multi-band) Wannier basis, computing the overlaps, and seeing what you can neglect. I don't know of any general results along these lines.